# JavaScript how to wait until a function and all its child functions are done

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my reactJS application I have the following button with an `onClick`

```
<Button
  onClick={() => {
    this.authenticateUser(this.state.user, this.state.password)
      .then(user => {
        if (user === "true") {
          this.setState({ markAsDone: true }, () => {
            this.startStepInstancePostConditions(this.props.step, this.props.instance.id);
            this.markSepInstanceAsDone(this.props.step, this.props.instance.id);
          });
          this.toggleDialog();
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.snackBarHandler(this.toggleSnackBar, "", t("auditLogs:newAuditLog.error"), 5000);
      });
  }}
>
  {t("processes:processStepInstances.markAsDoneDialog.save")}
</Button>
```

I'm not sure how to solve my problem.

the two functions:

```
this.startStepInstancePostConditions(this.props.step,this.props.instance.id);  

this.markSepInstanceAsDone(this.props.step,this.props.instance.id);
```

iterates over some arrays and do some `axios` posts.

I want that my application calls this:

```
 this.props.history.push("/processes/processInstance/" + this.props.instance.id);
```

if the above two functions and all theri child functions are done. how can I achive this?

Thanks in advance

Update:

```
export function markSepInstanceAsDone(step, processInstanceId) {
    const user = sessionStorage.getItem("username");
    const clientId = sessionStorage.getItem("client");
    axios.post(PROCESS_INSTANCES_URL + '/markProcessStepInstanceAsDone/' + clientId, {
        stepInstanceId: step.id,
        user: user,
        comment: this.state.markStepInstanceAsDoneComment
    })
        .then((response) => {
            this.getContentComponentPostConditions(step, processInstanceId);
            this.props.history.push("/processes/processInstance/" + processInstanceId);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.setState({dialogLoaded: false});
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Update

```
export function startStepInstancePostConditions(step,processInstanceID) {
    step.postConditions.map(postConditionTemplate => {
        axios.get(API_URL + '/processStepTemplates/' + postConditionTemplate.id)
            .then(response => {
                this.createProcessInstanceAutomatic(postConditionTemplate, response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have both of your functions return the promises from their axios calls, then you can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait until both of them are done, and do something afterward.

```
startStepInstancePostConditions() {
  return axios.post('...')
}
markSepInstanceAsDone() {
  return axios.post('...')
}

// inside the authenticateUser callback
Promise.all([
  this.startStepInstancePostConditions(this.props.step, this.props.instance.id),
  this.markSepInstanceAsDone(this.props.step, this.props.instance.id)
]).then(() => {
  this.props.history.push("/processes/processInstance/" + this.props.instance.id)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the Question and added the `markStepInstanceAsDone`

Comment: Change your functions to return the promises as I've suggested, like so: https://gist.github.com/kingdaro/12cf4a583adf4908b33df4b140bd316b

Comment: I changed it like you mentioned it, but its the same behaviour than bevore. the application does not wait until  `startStepInstancePostConditions` and `markSepInstanceAsDone` is finished

Comment: maybe this is an problem as well: `this.createProcessInstanceAutomatic(postConditionTemplate, response.data)` contains an axios post

Comment: do you maybe have 5 minutes for a skype call so I can show it to you and you maybe explain it to me?

Comment: Yes, _every_ promise has to be returned at the end somehow, otherwise JS won't wait for it. And no, I don't have the time, sorry

Comment: so I have to make each child function I call also to a promise? but then I lost the scope or?

Comment: I did it like you mentioned it, but now I have the problem when I call the page the child functions are called without button click. just on page load they are called ... what could be the problem?

Comment: If it's a different issue, make a new question

Comment: Just figured out I had a bug ;) was my fault. Thanks! Your solution works fine!